# Add tooltip to ACF Color Picker Field

Tags: jquery, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the following code to add custom colors to the ACF Color Picker field but would like to display a tool tip for each color on the palette:

```
function hra_acf_input_admin_footer()
{?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        acf.add_filter('color_picker_args', function(args, $field) {
            args.palettes = ['#ffffff', '#000000', '#c9c9c9', '#e0e0e0', '#f0f0f0', '#182c44', '#1f374f', '#345a7a'];
            // return colors
            return args;
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php }
add_action('acf/input/admin_footer', 'hra_acf_input_admin_footer');
```